# Number of non-zero solutions of an equation in $F \times F$ where $F$ is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $F$ be a field of order $32$.

Then I need to find the number of non-zero solutions $(a,b)$ $\in$ $F\times F$ of the equation $x^2+xy+y^2 = 0$.

I know that characteristic of a ring with unity $1$ is the order of $1$ in the group $(R,+).

Since $F$ has unity being a field, the order of unity i.e. $1$ divides $2^5$.

Since characteristic of a field is either $0$ or prime.

Since we have a finite field, hence characteristic can't be $0$ and hence it is $2$.

So the characteristic of $F \times F$ is $lcm(2,2)$ which is $2$.

Since order of $F \times F$ is $2^{32}$. So from here, can I say that $F \times F$ is a field?

If I can, then if $x = 0$ then $y$ will be $0$ and also the other way round.

So to get the required solutions, $x$ and $y$ both should be non-zero.

From here, how could I proceed?

Comment: The product of two fields is never a field since $(1,0)$ is a zero-divisor and thus a unit. On the other hand, there is only one field of order $32$, so you could brute force this problem (although there is presumably an easier solution)

Comment: $F=\mathbb{F}_{32}$ the unique field with 32 elements, is already known to have characteristic 2. Moreover, $F\times F$ is **not** a field, as it has zero divisors : $(1,0)\times(0,1)=(0,0)$. But from the characteristic two, you have : $$x^2+xy+y^2=0\iff (x+y)^2=xy.$$That may help? At last, $F\times F$ doesn't have $2^{32}$ elements, but rather $32^2$.

Comment: In a field of characteristic $2$ we have $(x+y)^2=x^2+y^2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that the characteristic of $F$ is $2$.

I think you misunderstood the role of $F \times F$ here, though. $(a,b) \in F \times F$ is just saying that $(a,b)$ is a pair of elements, each in $F$. That is, $a \in F$ and $b \in F$, just that we want to count the number of such pairs, where order matters. $F \times F$ is being used here simply as a set of pairs, not really as a field or even as a ring.

We're looking for solutions of $x^2 + xy + y^2 = 0$ where $x$ and $y$ are elements of $F$.

The answer is, there are no solutions (other than $(0,0)$).

As you noticed, the field properties give that if $x=0$ then $y=0$, and vice versa. So suppose $x$ and $y$ are elements in $F$ with $x \neq 0$, $y \neq 0$, and $x^2+xy+y^2=0$.

In any field, polynomial multiplication gives

$$ (x-y)(x^2 + xy + y^2) = x^3 - y^3 $$

So we must also have

$$x^3 - y^3 = (x-y) \cdot 0 $$
$$x^3 = y^3$$
$$(xy^{-1})^3 = 1$$

The multiplicative group of $F$ has $31$ elements ($0$ is not a member). Since $31$ is prime, that group is cyclic, so the multiplicative order of every element other than identity $1$ is $31$. So the only way the cube of $xy^{-1}$ can be $1$ is if $xy^{-1} = 1$. Then we must have $x=y$, so

$$0 = x^2+xy+y^2 = 3x^2 = x^2$$

But this would require $x=0$, contradicting the assumption. There cannot be any nonzero solutions.

Comment: That is a good solution. As a side comment: the multiplicative group of a field is always cyclic whatever  its order is.